# PHP absolute path not working

Tags: php, virtualhost

I have set up a simple virtual host.

JUST added these lines at the bottom

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/Reminder/"


    <Directory "/var/www/Reminder">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/Reminder/"
    </Directory>



    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/Reminder/" 
    ServerName test.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/yourdomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What I basically want is, while including files in php from files inside the Reminder folder, if I give an absolute path , like "/test/" , it should consider the Reminder folder as the root, and search for a test folder from inside Reminder.

Right now, when I type echo **DIR** , I am shown /var/www/Reminder.

my file structure is:

/var/www/Reminder/database/db_connect.php
/var/www/Reminder/registration/registration_handler.php

This is what my db_connect.php has :

```
<?php 

    define('DBHOST','localhost');
    define('DBUSER','root');
    define('DBPASS','password');
    define('DBNAME','Reminder');

    $conn=mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS) ;
    if(!$conn) { 

        echo mysqli_connect_error();

    }
    else {
        echo "connected successfully";
    }

?>
```

This is what my registration_handler has :

```
<?php
    echo "hi";
    echo __DIR__;
    require_once("/database/db_connect.php");

    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO users () VALUES ()") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

I believe, if everything is fine, I should be able to get the "connected successfully" message (from db_connect) , if I run registration_handler.php , but thats not happening.

When i include the same file like this :require_once("../database/db_connect.php"); , i get the output

Comment: `What I basically want is, ..., if I give an absolute path, ..., it should consider the Reminder folder as the root` php doesn't work like that - nor should it.

Comment: but, when I host some files in places like hostgater, doing '/' gives me the path of my websites root.

Answer (score 0):

The [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) option only restricts what paths you are allowed to access from PHP code. It does not affect the way file lookups from inside your PHP code works.

This means that setting `open_basedir` to `/var/www/Reminder/` will cause an error if you try to open for example `/etc/passwd` (because it is outside of the allowed the allowed directories). It will not transform an open of `/etc/passwd` into `/var/www/Reminder/etc/passwd`.

What you probably want instead is to use the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant in order to open by a relative path. For example, to load `/var/www/Reminder/database/db_connect.php` from `/var/www/Reminder/registration/registration_handler.php`, you would use something like:

```
$basedir = dirname(__DIR__);
require_once($basedir . '/database/db_connect.php');
```

We use `dirname()` to strip away the last path component from the end of `__DIR__`. I.e.:

- `__DIR__`: `/var/www/Reminder/registration`
- `dirname(__DIR__)`: `/var/www/Reminder`

Comment: I didn't notice that part. In that case using `__DIR__` should be safe, so I have updated the response. (I'm so used to people deploying code to ancient RHEL or CentOS installs that I am always hesitant to use anything "recent" in PHP.)